# find a client Side event of radGrid or Div that accure before any postback in page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

i have a customized radgrid in my page that some script have set for ongriddestroyed event. my script get all controls and their value in page and sent them with Ajax to server side. consider a buton on page too that cause a postback,  but i want my javascript code fire before any post back in page . i tryed window.onbeforeunload , it works fine till i use radajaxpanel or a update panel on page...
is there any javascript event that fire before any post back that i can set for my radGrid or its parent that is a div element?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.Net Ajax `RadAjaxManager` component of the telerik control suite 
provides a client side event handler called `OnRequestStart`.
`OnRequestStart` is called when an ajax request is started by

1. An control configured in RadAjaxManager
2. A control within a RadAjaxPanel
3. Client side ajaxRequest() call

So, the `OnRequestStart` handler is a good place to execute 
a client side script before an AJAX request is executed (e.g. triggered by an control inside an `RadAjaxPanel`).

You can also cancel the AJAX request in the `OnRequestStart` handler.

For more information see the [telerik online help](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-onrequeststart.html) on this topic.
You will also find an example there.